# R data.entry() can't open

Tags: r

when I call the function data.entry(), I got an error about losing a package "XQuartz", so I downloaded one and installed it.

When I tried again, I got a new error as follows:

'''
Error in .External2(C_dataentry, data, modes) : 
   unable to start data editor
In addition: Warning message:
In dataentry(odata, as.list(Modes)) : unable to open display
'''

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data.entry` behaviour varies wildly by system and GUI, and sometimes isn't supported at all in some builds, giving the error you report.  See `?data.entry` for some system specific details.

Please post your operating system/GUI details and your r version/details if you can't get it to work.

Additional notes:  The [source code for `data.entry()`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/modules/X11/dataentry.c#L1910) generates that error when it cannot resolve the `XOpenDisplay`command with the operating system's GUI environment.  On Linux, that usually means `X` is to blame.  `data.entry` is mostly intended for `Windows` because there are better alternatives on *unix systems and less `X` hair-ripping config frustrations.

[`RStudio`](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) may help you with visual data entry/editing with less debugging.

Another option is the package `RCmdr` which includes a visual editor that works on some platforms.  It's available on CRAN: [Rcmd package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcmdr/index.html)

Yet another option is to use the function `edit()` from the `utils` package instead of `data.entry`.  It has fewer dependencies on the platform.  See `?edit` or [utils::edit.data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/edit.data.frame.html)

Comment: Yeah, actually I am operating on my macbook pro and using the RStudio. I am actually a beginner of R and try for this clause. Maybe it's not available in Mac....

Comment: can I directly use RStudio interface to edit data in a spreadsheet like environment ? I see the view() function can view, sort, search. But it seems that it cannot edit?

Comment: Are you using `Rstudio` server?  If so, it explicitly does not have support for `data.entry`.  See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200659797-unable-to-view-data-with-fix-edit

If you're using the regular Mac `Rstudio` on top of a mac installation of R, then the issue is something else.

Comment: See edited answer for additional options for visual data editing.

Comment: Yeah, I am using RStudio on top of a regular installation of R.